# Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I tried to Set up GCM in my project as given in [Set up a GCM Client App on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) and to [Set Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#play-services) added dependency

```
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0"
```

to the dependency section of my application's **build.gradle** file.

And In the root gradle file add classpath as given in sample project(Sample cloned from `$ git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git`) as

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta6'
}
```

It's building fine, but it crashes on launch with the following stack trace :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5156)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
>                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx.zzy(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzaU(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
>                                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5153)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Also tried related stack questions:

1. [Updating Play services from 8.1 to 8.3 with Proguard enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571555/updating-play-services-from-8-1-to-8-3-with-proguard-enabled)
2. [Error on some devices - couldn't find class
   'com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzz'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196015/error-on-some-devices-couldnt-find-class-com-google-android-gms-measurement)

As answered in 1st link tried classpath

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'
```

and as answered in 2nd link,tried Multidex also with no success.

Also tried for **Application Measurement**  adding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <integer name="google_app_measurement_enable">0</integer>
</resources>
```

as suggested in [Play Services Release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#september_2015_-_v81).

Note : sample code running.

---

**Update :**

Interesting thing is that same error even if I add only dependency

```
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0"
```

in my app gradle file(Note : Only one line added in Existing project).And there is no error after adding

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0"
```

i.e. the token works on **8.1.0**.Interesting,isn't?

Comment: There is no method `com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx.zzy` in 8.4.0. Are you sure you don't mix mutliple gms modules with different versions? Maybe across multiple build.gradle files.

Comment: Will check and let you know.

Comment: All gms modules having same version 8.4.0 in app gradle file only.

Answer (score 5):

Did you remember to add the plugin to the **end** of your app-level build.gradle file? ...

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

You specifically need to add it to the **very end** of the file.

Take a look here for reference: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/build.gradle

There is also a bug report opened on this issue: [Issue 193112](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193112)

Comment: @GiruBhai - I actually did read the question "properly", my friend. You had failed to mention that you included the plugin line in your Gradle file. I also mentioned a bug report on this issue, which there are several. I would suggest that you read through those bug reports a bit more. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

From Android studio menu go to:

- Build → Clean Project
- Build → Rebuild Project
- Run the app. No more crash.

Note: I am using the latest version of play-services:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

Comment: Thanks to answer but Its not working even did restart AS.And also as suggested by play services "From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play service APIs into your app".So we add `  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0"
`compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0"` to escape from dex limit.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your classpath dependency, instead of '*classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta6*'', use *classpath '
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'*'.

Here is a related  [stack overflow ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593632/proguard-obfuscation-issues-after-adding-new-google-sign-in-to-android-applicati), you may check the solution offered by community:. It was stated that they already filed bug ticket and the said fix has been implemented in release 1.5.0 of the foot service plugin.