# Application is not running in android 4.4

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I am using below gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.radtek.dlms_detroit"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}


dependencies {
    //compile project(':captureActivity')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile files('libs/DataCollection.jar')
    compile files('libs/guice-3.0-no_aop.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/roboguice-2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile files('libs/ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
    // Include the Google Maps Android API from Google Play Services.
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'

    compile files('libs/aspectjrt-1.7.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/isoparser-1.0.6.jar')
}
```

It's building fine, but it crashes on launch with the following stack trace :

Logcat Error :

```
05-24 18:16:19.765 4940-4940/com.radtek.dlms_detroit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.radtek.dlms_detroit-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.radtek.dlms_detroit-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4793)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.radtek.dlms_detroit-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.radtek.dlms_detroit-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Also tried related stack questions:

1.[Updating Play services from 8.1 to 8.3 with Proguard enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571555/updating-play-services-from-8-1-to-8-3-with-proguard-enabled)

2.[Error on some devices - couldn't find class 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzz'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196015/error-on-some-devices-couldnt-find-class-com-google-android-gms-measurement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some classes are missing because multidex is not working properly. You will have to edit your Application class for multidex to work prior to 5.0. Make it extend MuliDexApplication like this

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

Or if you do not have an application class add this in your manifest instead

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp">
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: it worked for me.. Now i am not getting any crash. But keyboard is not opening in android 4.4. @Suhaib plz suggest.

Comment: Ask a different question with the scenario